# Admin template override ignored title block

Tags: django, django-admin, django-templates

The title block is not overriding when creating a custom version of base_site.html in `/project_dir/templates/admin/base_site.html`. The correct template is being rendered, however the title/branding block does not change on the page even when setting the blocks as follows. I have a hunch that the issue is related to django_admin_tools, but am not sure yet at this time.

```
{% block title %}Super Awesome new admin title{% endblock %}
```

and

```
{% block branding %}
    <h1 id="site-name">Super Awesome new admin branding</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

**Edit:**

results of grep for `{% block branding %}` in both the project and in python libs finds it in 4 locations

```
$ grep -r "{% block branding %}" /path/to/
/path/to/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/admin_tools/theming/templates/admin/base.html:        {% block branding %}{% endblock %}
/path/to/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/admin_tools/menu/templates/admin/base_site.html:{% block branding %}
/path/to/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.3.1-py2.7.egg/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/base.html:        {% block branding %}{% endblock %}
/path/to/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.3.1-py2.7.egg/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/base_site.html:{% block branding %}
/path/to/project/templates/admin/base.html:        {% block branding %}{% endblock %}
/path/to/project/templates/admin/base_site.html:{% block branding %}
```

In the project base_site.html I change `{% load i18n admin_tools_menu_tags %}` to something wrong like `{% load i18nn admin_tools_menu_tags %}` (add an n to i18n) and get an error so I know the template is at least being correctly chosen.

Any suggestions on what would be causing my blocks to be ignored or overridden somewhere else? As shown above, I don't see where else they could possibly be overridden.

Thanks.

Comment: I think more information would be helpful. Are you saying editing your base.html in `/project_dir/templates/admin/` is not working? perhaps provide your structure, templates_dir in settings. What you're editing where and what your attempting to edit(does it have to do with an administrative area)? At this point it could be a several things.

Comment: I have updated the question considerably after I found more information. I am leaving it here as it's still an issue, but beginning to feel like I'm getting closer to a solution now that I know it's related to the two blocks not happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django admin tools uses a photo to brand the admin....not the branding block.